# Expire Cookie of Password Protected WordPress Page on Click

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, password-protection

I was creating password protected pages on WordPress. Now the standard expiry time for cookie is 10 days. (Which logs them out of wp password protected page). I found the code to add to theme's functions.php file to set custom expiry time which is:

```
add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'wpse_custom_post_password_expires' );
function wpse_custom_post_password_expires( $expires ) {
    return time() + 30; // Expire in 30 seconds
}
```

But I want to create a click event (on some button/icon) and make cookie expire. (Since there is currently no way to log out of password protected page)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Same way, as you make any other cookie “expire” - you _delete_ it. And for that, you first of all need to know its name. Do you have that?

Comment: Um no actually many password protected pages will be created and sent to each of my clients. And I was planning that each password protected page has a logout button that onclick can generically somehow expire that cookie

Comment: That was not the point of my question. WP _generates_ the cookie name dynamically, out of a static prefix, and a hash of some values. If you want to specifically delete _that_ cookie, then you would need to find out its name first. Assuming that no client will have to _different_ such cookies at any given time though, you could simply loop through all cookie, and see which one has the same prefix, and then delete it.

Comment: I don’t know if WordPress itself provides any mechanism for that. (Probably not though, I would assume – this is meant as a measure of access control, but not _really_ as a “login”.)

Comment: Btw Do you think there is way to instead of password protecting the page, I can create a user login and provide him the url and credentials which can log him into and out of wordpress page to see only his content